# Alternative constructions of the Vitali Set

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Wikipedia defines the Vitali Set in the following way:

> A subset V of the interval $[0,1]$ of real numbers such that for each $r \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists exactly one number $v \in V$ such that $v-r$ is a rational number.

The article then goes on to show that this set is non-measurable.

However, my lecture notes presents an alternative definition of the Vitali Set to show non-measurability and was wondering if these definitions are equivalent. They use the following definition:

> Consider the interval $\mathbb{S}^1 = [0,1)$ with the angle addition operation $x \bigoplus y = x+y$ mod $1$. There exists a set $V \subseteq [0,1)$ that decomposes $\mathbb{S}^1$ into disjoint sets $V_1, V_2,V_3 ...$ which are translations of $V$.

These definitions appear to be quite different from one another, however, both are referred to as the Vitali Set. And both of these seem to be sets that are non-measurable. Am I correct to assume that these are equivalent constructions?

Comment: Note that there is no single "Vitali set". *Each* choice of equivalence class representatives will give one Vitali set; but they all share the same basic properties that lead to them being non-measurable. Given any Vitali set $V$, it contains a unique rational $q$; replacing $q$ with a different rational will give a different "Vitali set", so that's at least countably many different sets. We call it "the" Vitali set, but really shouldn't.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Okay, so if I'm understanding correctly, the two examples in the question are different sets (that we call Vitali Sets) but possess the same underlying characteristics that make all these "Vitali Sets" non-measurable. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: I was trying to point out that there isn't a single "Vitali set"; you won't be able to prove that two constructions yield "the same set", because there isn't a single target set you are "aiming" for. Also, your second quote is not a definition or a construction: the second quote claims that a set exists with a certain properties. The set $V$ in your first quote satisfies these properties. But the second one you give cannot be understood to be a "definition", or a "construction".

Comment: Sorry, I phrased that poorly. What I was trying to ask was whether or not the set $V$ in the second quote must be the same $V$ that is defined in the first quote. Or if we can construct other "Vitali Sets" that satisfy the claim made in the second quote @ArturoMagidin

Comment: For a moment I thought that the "Angel Addition" referred to something shaped like an angel. Then I realized it is just a typo and it is "Angle Addition". :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first definition, the set $V$  is a set of distinct representatives of the equivalence classes that arise from the equivalence relation of having a rational difference. So such a set $V$ (which is not unique) is obtained by a direct application of the axiom of choice.

A set $V$ that satisfies the first definition automatically satisfies the second definition, where the relevant translations are translations mod 1 by all rationals in $[0,1)$.

However, it is possible to obtain an example satisfying the second definition using any countable  additive subgroup of $[0,1)$ with addition mod 1 (instead of the rationals.) For instance, we could use the set of dyadic rationals, or the set of algebraic numbers in $[0,1)$. Such a construction will not satisfy the first definition.